# Populating peripheral with advertisementData

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am writing a Swift app to communicate with Arduino. In the following function I am handling `didDiscover` event adding the found peripheral to list of my peripherals. The problem is that peripherals are not populated with services which are correctly found and stored in `advertisementData`. How can I populate peripheral with data from `advertisementData`?

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                    advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)
{
    let existingDevice = devices.first { $0.identifier == peripheral.identifier }
    if existingDevice == nil {
        devices.append(peripheral)
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    // Handle successful connection
    isConnected = true
    selectedDevice = peripheral
    selectedDevice?.delegate = self
    selectedDevice?.discoverServices([targetServiceUUID])
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    guard let services = peripheral.services else {
        // Handle error or no services found
        return
    }

    for service in services {
        print("Discovered service: \(service)")
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service) // Passing nil will discover all characteristics
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `discoverService` on that peripheral.

Comment: I tried to do it just by adding "peripheral.discoverServices(nil)" before "devices.append" line alongside with implementation of "func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)" but it changes nothing as the peripheral function with didDiscoverServices tag is never called

Comment: You need to set the delegate, if not the method won't be called.

Comment: I did set the delegate as "selectedDevice?.delegate = self". I was able to get a device with correctly found devices twice however it was matter of long wait. May the issue be caused by long time needed for BLE to find all services? 

I also moved the discoverServices to cetralManager extension with didConnect tag this time, trying to not find all services (nil) but specific one with specific UUID but I am no getting it despite I am 100% sure the device is broadcasting it.

Comment: Also coming back to my question from the post, the 'advertisementData' has the service correctly found, why I have to call discover services when I already have it found and stored in this array? Shouldn't there be way to use this data instead of calling same thing again? By same thing I mean that discoverServices must be somehow called already if 'advertisementData' is correctly populated? Or is it like the discoverService is actually just getting them from this array not searching them again?

Comment: No, in advertisementData, there can be anything. It won't fetch itself the services, to avoid connection (after all it's the "LE" of "BLE"). It could advertise a service it doesn't have. But once you discovered it, it's added to the peripheral, you can retrieve it from it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification with advertisementData now I fully understand this mechanism. 

About the DiscoverServices, what can be issue on my side that it doesn't capture any of them and doesn't invoke cetralManager extension with didConnect tag? Like I stated I made a delegate with selectedDevice?.delegate = self but it still doesn't work as It is supposed to. 

Also is the discoverServices function which have to end to proceed or its executed in the background letting program to continue while searching?

Comment: You need to show more code, currently, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I added more code to the post, if its not enough I may add you to the GitHub repo